# How can I create a function with the behaviour of the duplicate option of dropdown menu? In Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want to put a button to duplicate an object. Then, modify some fields of it and then, save it into database, in Odoo 9.

That is exactly what does the duplicate option in the dropdown menu, but I want it in a header button.

I have created the button, put it in the form header and associated to this python function:

```py
def button_duplicate_register(self):
  new_sale_order_id = self.copy().id
  return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'sale.order',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': new_sale_order_id,
        'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True, 'options': {'mode': 'edit'}}},
    }
```

With this code, I duplicate the object, and then, the user is redirected to the new object in edit mode. Then, the user can change fields, and click on the **save** button. Everything is fine.

The problem is if the user clicks on the **discard** button instead of **save**. The changes will be discarded but the object has already been duplicated and stored in the database.

How can I duplicate a register but not save it to the database until the user clicks on **save** button?

Answer (score 1):

I seeing one possibility.

You custom button open a wizard. This wizard is the representation of your model you would like duplicate. And you do not call your method duplicate but you create a new record and open it in edit mode.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. That works, but I have the same problem. The record is created and then is opened in edit mode. But I do not want to write anything in the database until the user clicks on SAVE button (inside the edit mode). 
That is how it works if you select duplicate option

Comment: Maybe I did not understand well your answer. How can I call the wizard?

Comment: Sorry for response time, When I speaking about wizard I imagine this. You create a model, this model is transianteModel. In this model, you create fields, this fields is a representation of sale.order fields. Your users enter the value of the wizard and after when your user click on the execute of the wizard, in your method execute, you created a new record of sale.order with the value of your wizard and return an ir.action.window to open your new record sale order created.

Comment: Well, I have to create a wizard for 'sale.order' and another wizard for 'sale.order.line'.
Then, when the user clicks on execute, I create the sale.order and sale.order.line(s) copying them from wizards. 
Finally, I delete the wizard records and redirect the user to the created sale.order.
Is everything correct?